# Use of undeclared type when using swift files

Tags: xcode, swift

Im trying to use a star rating system in my app, which can be found at this link: https://github.com/exchangegroup/star-rating-view. I dragged and dropped the files into my project, but for some reason when I try to create an IBOutlet for ratings view as a "TagStarRatingView" I always get an error that says "Use of undeclared type TegStarRating". Im confused as to why im getting this error because the file TegStarRating files are coded in swift so i shouldnt need to import them in the bridging header. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I see that the undeclared type is T**e**gStarRating... Maybe the outlet has an e instead of an a?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also have to drag and drop it into the right group. Following the instructions on github:

> 1. Copy `.swift` files under `start-rating-view` group into your project.
> 2. Add View control into your storyboard. Set its class to `TegStarRatingView`.
> 3. Add an outlet for this view in your view controller.
> 4. Use `show` method to display rating:

Comment: wow in all my time programing with xcode i totally did not know this simple detail! Thanks!